# Convergence of series/integral

Tags: calculus

[image]

The first one is false because one of the requirements of the integral test is that $f(x)=\frac{\cos{(x+1)}}{x^{3/2}}$ be positive which it is NOT (it is oscillating). In fact we use the comparison test where we compare to $\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ which converges.

For the second one do we compare to $$\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-x} \; dx?$$
Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, I would do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{x} \; dx<\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-x} \; dx$

Since the integral is a increasing application and $\frac{e^{-x}}{x} <e^{-x}$

And :

$\frac{e^{-x}}{x} >0$

Therefore the comparison test is successful